# Lead Generation

Tags: web2lead

Why in case of web-to-lead we can enter null value in the web-lead page, but the Salesforce field it looks like the image below?
[image: Null Lead]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO

The [Lead object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm?search_text=lead) has two required fields

- `Company`
- `LastName`

without these values, the Lead record cannot be saved

The W2L servlet coerces value of `[not provided]` into the `Lead.Company` and `Lead.LastName` fields so as to ensure a lead created on a W2L form is saved (e.g., perhaps only an email + description is provided by the user)

If you want to make sure that W2L leads include a "real" value for Company and LastName, you need to extend the HTML that the W2L process generates. See [SFDC help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325377&type=1&mode=1) on how to do this (or see [this SFDC Success post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gw5kAAA)

Comment: But why it is accepting null value from web-to-lead and populating the field with [not provided]?

Comment: Because the SFDC-supplied W2L servlet coerces that value to ensure a Lead is saved.  The W2L form needs to be extended to enforce a value in the user's browser.

Comment: So it is salesforce's default strategy for not losing a lead then. Thank you very much Sir. Can you please look at my other question regarding to queues.

Comment: Sam - as a service to the Community, you should accept the answer so others can benefit from your question; I see other contributors are looking at your Queue question

Answer (score -1):

Its not null values. 
Its just placeholder text that will be stored is required fields since it cannot be blank.

Comment: What is a place holder value and when/in which case salesforce use it?